# How to get the credential when using Firebase pre-built UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using phone number as a login method with the pre-built UI provided by Firebase, and I need to keep the verificationID for future use. However, I'm not able to figure how to retrieve the verificationID (the SMS code sent to user).
I know I can retrieve it using the callbacks shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) but I'm not sure how to put this together when using the Firebase pre-built UI.
Any help or lead to solve this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Firebase pre-built UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui), you don't need to explicitly handle the phone authentication flow. It is handled for you entirely by the widget.

Check the [sign-in example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui#sign_in).

As long as you `new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()` as authentication provider, the entire flow will be handled for you.